# In Asp.Net core, how can I catch the event that a form was submitted AND has passed clientside validation?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Scenario:

On a form, I want to disable the submit button when it is clicked and form has passed clientside validation (to avoid double-click double-submits).

If I listen to the form submit event, it fires (obviously) even when the form is not valid clientside.

Using js, how can I know if the form passed validation (clientside)?

I am using Asp.Net MVC (not razor pages, just razor syntax), .Net core 7.

Comment: ` ($('#form-name'). valid();` should work. https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/

Answer (score 0):

in the controller method that handles the form submit, you can return view with the model. like so;

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SubmitForm(MyViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Do something with the valid model data
        return View("MyViewName", model); // or maybe "return RedirectToAction("Wherever");" here, depends on what you want to do after successful operation.

    }
    else
    {
        return View("MyViewName", model);
    }
}
```

this will force a refresh on the page. since the view was returned with the model, the text in all textboxes etc. will remain.

to disable the button when it got clicked once, do this;

```
<form>
  <!-- your form fields go here -->
  <button type="submit" id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
  const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit-btn');
  submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    submitBtn.disabled = true;
  });
</script>
```

this will make it so the button gets disabled when it got clicked once. the disabled state will go away when the controller responds (when the page is refreshed). this should happen very fast anyway, but in case it takes several seconds, the button will stay disabled until a response is received from the server. this should achieve the effect you desired.

please note that this is NOT a security measure. what we are doing is disabling the button on client-side, which is easily bypassable. if you are concerned with consecutive submissions of any sort, you MUST implement necessary additional server-side protection (in addition to model validation).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't really address my issue... If I disable the button after a click - and validation (clientside) fails, then I am now stuck in state where the form is not submitted - and the button to submit it is now disabled. That is why I am looking for another event, which fires when the form is submitted AND the form is validated (ie when the form is actually posted back to the controller).

Comment: you can't be stuck. have you tried the code? the controller method returns view upon validation failure which refreshes the page, which resets the button.

Comment: you said "validation (clientside)", are you doing validation clientside? if so, why didn't you include this information in your question? I assumed you would be doing validation in server-side since that's the standard and safest way of doing it. Nevertheless, I recommend you move validation to server side since it's much safer that way.

Comment: @metphisto Sorry, I should have made it clear I meant clientside validation. And it does not submit the form to the controller unless it passes clientside validation. Otherwise you are right, then returning the view including model from the controller would reset the disabled button.

Comment: if you really want to stick with client-side validation, you will need to provide your code, as we can't guess your code. but since server-side validation is necessary regardless of whether you validate in client-side or not, I would recommend implementing my suggestion altogether, because client-side validation is generally not secure.

Comment: but here is also a different approach which you may prefer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64127826/18391068

Answer (score 0):

If you validate with attribute, You can not submit until they are validated.

```
public class Userprofile
    {
        [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z\s]*$")]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

```
@model testproject.Models.UserProfile
<form method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
    
@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}
```

[image]